# nuxt3 porting nuxtServerInit with req object access

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Porting a nuxt2 application that uses nuxtServerInit to setup a few things based on the request headers.  In nuxt3 I created a plugin init.server.ts and can't figure out how to access the request object.

Any insight on how to get access to it?

Answer (score 0):

const headers = useRequestHeaders()